# Generate mixed strings limited to a number of characters from items in a list

Tags: python, list, limit

I intend on taking the string values in a list to find different combinations of the sub strings that make full use of the 25 character limit.

I'm currently dealing with this issue:

If I have a list with the values:

```
lorem = ['when', 'the fox jumped over the moon']
```

due to the second string in the list, the result is:

```
limited = ['when']

lorem = ['when', 'the fox jumped', 'over', 'the moon']
```

I want an algorithm that'll:

1. Search through the entirely of the list of strings.
2. Attempt to generate a strings of all combinations to make full use of the character limit.
3. Print 3-5 different results (say number 1's len was 23, number 2 22, number 3 18 etc etc)

something like:

```
limited = ['the fox jumped the moon']

..
..
```

I hope this is clear and makes sense.

*current code*:

```
title_limited = []
counter = 0
while counter < 25:
    for i in lorem:
        counter += len(i)
        if counter > 25: break
        title_limited.append(i.title())
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post the code, not a image of the code

Comment: @JoaoVitorino of course, added.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import itertools

x_raw=[el.split(' ') for el in lorem] 
x=[el for sublist in x_raw for el in sublist] #Not sure if I understood, what do you mean by "substring" - these 2 lines will produce substring ~ word

n=25 # character limit

res=[]
for i in range(len(x)):
   for obj in itertools.combinations(x, i+1):
      res_temp = " ".join(obj)
      #to ensure total number of characters <25 but it's high enough, that no other word from lorem/x will fit
      if((len(res_temp) < n) and (n-len(res_temp)<=min([len(el) for el in [el_x for el_x in x if el_x not in obj]] or [100]))): res.append(res_temp)
```

Comment: Hi @Grzegorz Skibinski, this returns ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence.

Comment: Hm, odd - try now. This error is coming from the empty "obj". Not sure why it's empty though - I tried different combinations of input data, but wasn't able to reproduce. The above should mitigate it (It defaults length of remaining strings to 100 - make it more, if you need). I'm on python 3.7